# Visual Studio 2017 c# 7.0 search for gray dots

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I want to refractor my codes with C# 7, and visual studio 2017 have this very cool way of knowing where to identify them by putting the gray dots on the scroll bar. If anyone have any idea how i could search through my solution for those gray dots is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of those "gray dots"? I'm not sure what you're referring to. Some of the markings that appear in the scroll bar are showing you search results, others are showing bookmarks, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, what you want is this:

[image]

Which points to here:

[image]

In order to customize which messages appear and how, configure the wanted options under

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style
```